# Gmail Chat: the heart

Tags: gmail

It's not a very important question, but it's important for me. I'm using the Gmail chat with friend and with colleagues and when I write an heart it's doing that: [image]

And when my colleagues make an heart too with the same bind ( `<3` ) it's doing that: [image]

Why it's not the same?

And how I can do the big heart with gmail chat?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: is this question seriously related to stackoverflow and the contents of this website? read the FAQ please

Comment: I'm sorry but it's a computing question on a new technology of gmail...

Comment: @SarahTaylor: StackOverflow is for **programming** questions.  You're looking for WebApps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use different emoticons. Click on the smile on the right bottom side of the input box, and change your emoticons..

Answer (score 2):

You can choose "theme" in gmail chat by clicking on the blue smiley in textbox.